# Why is "using getString() to get device identifiers" not recommended?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get my device ID to Logcat but Android Studio is giving me this warning.

> using getstring to get device identifiers is not recommended

```
String deviceID = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Why is it not recommended?

Comment: Which warning ?

Comment: It seems like the problem is not the fact that you used getString but that you should not be using hardware ids in your app at all. See: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html

Comment: @StarterPack actually the deal is whether the id is resettable or not (ids like the IMEI are not resettable, ANDROID_ID is through factory reset). So I believe it is possible to use ANDROID_ID, but I find it weird that this warning is displayed in AS.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The full warning says:

> Using these device identifiers is not recommended other
> than for high value fraud prevention and advanced telephony use-cases.
> For advertising use-cases, use AdvertisingIdClient$Info#getId and for
> analytics, use InstanceId#getId.
>
> More info:
> https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html

I think Android does not recommend using this value, since it's a permanent unique id, which can be used to track your user, and he or she can't change this id or prevent you to read it. The other options given in the warning respects your user's wishes. That's why Android recommend you to use that.

It really depends on what you are going to do with that id. Privacy is a sensitive thing these days.

Also check this:

> ...you must abide by a user’s ‘Opt out of interest-based advertising’
> or 'Opt out of Ads Personalization' setting. If a user has enabled
> this setting, you may not use the advertising identifier for creating
> user profiles for advertising purposes or for targeting users with
> personalized advertising. Allowed activities include contextual
> advertising, frequency capping, conversion tracking, reporting and
> security and fraud detection.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html

Comment: So, what is the solution now, what should be used instead of this ID?

Comment: Again! What should be used instead of this ID?

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong by using the `Secure.ANDROID_ID`. It's just a warning. I would say, if you need an id for Analytics, use `InstanceId.getId()`, for advertising use `AdvertisingIdClient.Info.getId()` and when both don't fit your needs, use `Secure.ANDROID_ID`. Keep in mind that a rooted user can change this id.

Comment: To sum up: preferably use either one alternative or the other, and when you can't, then mute this warning (for example for a single method).

Comment: I think using this ID is valid if you want to ban a user for terms of service infringement.

Comment: We are using this ID to distinguish between user's devices. As we are keeping FCM tokens on server, we need to know if new token is actually a new device, or is it an old one and should be replaced. We do not want to end up with dozens of tokens for the same user having a single device. Is there a better solution to such problem?

Answer (score 1):

The warning you're seeing is related to the use of `Settings.Secure.getString()` to retrieve device identifiers like the Android ID. This approach is generally not recommended for a few reasons:

#### Reasons:

1. **Privacy Concerns**: Accessing device identifiers can pose privacy risks and may be against the policies of some app stores.
2. **Unreliable Identifiers**: The Android ID can change upon performing a factory reset, and it can be null for some devices. It's also possible for it to be easily altered on a rooted device.
3. **Limited Use Cases**: Android IDs are not suitable for several use-cases like user authentication, analytics tracking, etc., due to their limitations.

#### Alternatives:

1. **Instance ID**: This provides a unique identifier for each app instance and is suitable for most use-cases that need a unique identifier.

   ```kotlin
   FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
       .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
           if (!task.isSuccessful) {
               return@OnCompleteListener
           }
           val token = task.result?.token
       })
   ```
2. **GUID (Globally Unique Identifier)**: If you just need a unique identifier for each installation or user session, consider generating a GUID upon app installation and storing it in `SharedPreferences`.

   ```kotlin
   val uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
   ```
3. **Use Advertising ID for Advertising**: If you need the identifier for advertising purposes, consider using Google's Advertising ID, which is user-resettable and recommended for advertising use-cases.

   ```kotlin
   AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context).id
   ```
4. **Scoped Storage or App-Specific IDs**: For device identification that doesn't need to persist across app installations, you can use identifiers that are scoped to your app's storage or generate a random ID and store it in your app's local storage.

#### Code Refactoring:

If you decide to use Instance ID, your utility function could look like this:

```kotlin
class DeviceUtils {
    fun getDeviceId(context: Context, callback: (String) -> Unit) {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
            .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    callback(task.result?.token ?: "")
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Remember to add the necessary Firebase dependencies to your `build.gradle` file.

Happy coding!